# Flutter LBS to KG design

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Im trying to make a design that I have drawed here:

[image]

My code is now:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Build a Form widget using the _formKey we created above
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          new Text(
            'LBS: ',
          ),
          TextFormField(
            validator: (value) {
              if (value.isEmpty) {
                return 'Please enter LBS';
              }
            },
          ),

          new Text(
            'KG: ',
          ),
          new Text(
            '{kg value} ',
          ),

          new Row(
              new RaisedButton(
                onPressed: null,
                child: Text('Convert'),
              ),
              new RaisedButton(
                onPressed: null,
                child: Text('Swap'),
              )

          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

My problem is the New row where I want to have the two buttons.
"new Row(" doesnt expect arguments.

Comment: you need to wrap your buttons into a `children: <Widget> [ ... ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your buttons into a children:  [ ... ]

```
Row(
        children: <Widget>[
                    new RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: null,
                    child: Text('Convert'),
                  ),
                  new RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: null,
                    child: Text('Swap'),
            ],
        )
```